# how to obtain ref to shadowRoot which contains given element

Tags: javascript, web-component, shadow-dom

I am using web components.

I have a node tree like this, as described by the chrome dev tools inspector:

```
<div>
-- <my-fancy-custom-elem> (this is the web component)
---- #shadow-root
------ <div class="button-container">
-------- <button class="a-button-in-a-web-comp">
```

I am able to obtain a reference to the `<button>` through an event listener initiated outside of the web component's class.

Similar to this:

```
document.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
   const clickedElem = event.composedPath()[0]
   if(clickedElem.matches('.a-button-in-a-web-comp')){
     console.log(clickedElem.parentNode.parentNode)
   }
});
```

I can get a reference to the `#shadow-root` by calling `clickedElem.parentNode.parentNode`. However I am looking for a means to reliably get the shadow-root ancestor of that `<button>` no matter how deep in the tree it lives. And even if I don't know how deep in the tree it lives.

In other words I am looking for a way to reliably return the first shadow-root that contains X element, when I have a reference to X.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call `clickedElem.getRootNode()` to get the shadowRoot , as shown in the snippet below:

```js
class CustomButton extends HTMLElement{
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.attachShadow({"mode": "open"});
    this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = `
      <div>
        <button class="a-button-in-a-web-comp">Button</button>
       </div>
    `;
  }
}
customElements.define('custom-button', CustomButton);

document.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
   const clickedElem = event.composedPath()[0];
   if(clickedElem.matches('.a-button-in-a-web-comp')){
     console.log(clickedElem.getRootNode())
   }
})
```

```html
<custom-button></custom-button>
```

Comment: You can chain: ``this.attachShadow({"mode": "open"}).innerHTML= .... ``